# Links turning blue for a fr. of a second when I add transition time in CSS

Tags: css, button, hyperlink, hover

I have this problem.
When I give a transition time to the menu links (for :hover and :active), once I click them they turn blue for a sec.
I also have 2 button links, which have transition time but they don't turn blue when I click.

I tried wrapping the the li-tag with the anchor-tag and viceversa, but nothing changed.
Anybody knows why this happens for the menu links but not for the buttons?

```css
.menu {
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 27px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  padding-top: 1px;
  background: rgb(255, 224, 189);
}

.menuitem {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .8s;
}

.menuitem:hover {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px black;
}

.menuitem:active {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px black;
  transform: scale(.5);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="item home"><a class="current menuitem" href="index1.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="item cani"><a href="cani.html" class="menuitem">Cani</a></li>
    <li class="item gatti"> <a href="gatti.html" class="menuitem">Gatti</a></li>
    <li class="item comeaiutarci"><a href="comeaiutarci.html" class="menuitem">Come aiutarci</a></li>
    <li class="item contatti"><a href="contatti.html" class="menuitem">Contatti</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hi Mathew, welcome to SO! If you want to get proper help on SO you will need to post a [reprex] of what you tried to achieve. Right now, we can only guess....

Comment: Done. Thank you for the suggestion. I just had issues with posting the code in the right way.

Comment: What browser are you using? On W10 Chrome/Edge and Firefox the 'blue' flicker does not show. Also, you don't use 'blue' anywhere, so it might be the `outline` showing: elements that can get `:focus` (like `<a>`, `<button>`,`<input>`) get an `outline` drawn around them (usually 'light blue'-ish) when clicked/tapped. Maybe try `transition:  color,text-shadow .8s;` (meaning: only transition the 'color' and 'text-shadow' properties)

Comment: I noticed that with the 'beige' background color the `text-shadow` may get a very slight 'blue-ish' feel, but that is purely optical and may depend on PC graphics driver/screen settings. Very vague reason, though, just me thinking out loud.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the tip. I am using Google Chrome 84.0.4147.105. I just updated it

Comment: Same here, tried it again, no flicker. But it may be that your display has a bit of a blue tone (cold color settings, 9400K) which would make the `text-shadow` seem blue-ish. So, a not reproducible issue...